# FTDI d2xx driver not reading bytes on Android to communicate with MDB board to Vending Machine

Tags: uart, android, ftdi, usb-host, usb-otg

When trying the D2xx driver from FTDI, there was no bytes being read by Android Device.

Below are the codes:

when opening a port to use (since only 1 port in android it is default to the first port in list of devices function from the UARTmanager). followed from one of the answer in this website to use restartintask

```
private void openFunction() throws Exception
{
    this.ftDev = UARTManager.openByIndex(SerialContext, portToUse);

    if (!ftDev.isOpen())
    {
        throw new Exception("openFunction -- SerialCommunicator: Unable To open FTDI device for communication.");
    }

    this.ftDev.restartInTask();
}
```

once it connected, tried sending a message:

```
int status = ftDev.write(byteToSend, byteToSend.length);
this.trace("send Status: " + Integer.toString(status));
```

- the Problem here is the status return from the write is always 5, there is no documentation in the FTDI website that tells what meaning of each status return is after write operation. the length of bytetosend was 2

when reading from the hardware containing the FTDI chipset:

```
public byte serialReadByte()
{
    this.readCompleted = false;

    new ReadAsyncTask().execute();

    while(!this.readCompleted) {}

    if(this.fromSerial != null && this.fromSerial.length > 0)
    {
        return this.fromSerial[0];
    }

    return null;
}

private class ReadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   

            int totalRead = ftDev.getQueueStatus();

            fromSerial = new byte[1];

            if(totalRead > 0)
            {
                ftDev.read(fromSerial, 1);          
            }

            readCompleted = true;

            return null;
        }

    }
```

- the problem here is nothing is being return from the read. Followed from one of the answers here to put it in a thread as seen in current code

out of option here, maybe you guys have any idea about this? the FTDI model is FT230XS-R and using the FTDI Driver's UARTManager.

Searched for other driver available in the internet, only to find it only supports FT232, maybe you guys could suggest a driver that works for the FT230XS-R FTDI chipset?

Comment: the settings for the port is here: baudRate = 921600; 
    stopBit = 0x00;  //1 stop bit
    dataBit = 0x08; // 8 data bit
    parity = 0x00; // none
    flowControl = 0x0; // none

Comment: baud rates tried are 9600 and 115200

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering where you searched for the return values, because if I type "Android D2XX FTDI" into Google it *immediately* and firstly returns to me [this PDF](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_233_Java_D2xx_for_Android_API_User_Manual.pdf).

Which very simply tells you the return values to check for in each function. In this case (page 47) it's the number of bytes written, not a status.

So it seems you are *not* sending just 2 bytes and not receiving any data does not have to be in your FTDI system, but can easily be in whatever you connected. Which you do not talk about. If you expect to send 2 bytes and send 5 bytes, it's possible you're also not sending the bytes you think you send.

You also say you tried different Baud rates. What does the hardware connected think of this? Did you reconfigure that? With UARTs, devices need to agree to the communication speed in detail.

It's also possible something else is going wrong in your connection that you forgot to check for, but that I cannot say, since I avoid Java like the plague. (Call it a personal preference)

On page 30 you can also see how to build up checks to prevent any untraceable errors.

Comment: Hi, after posting the comments, tried for a last search and found out it returned the byte read. but still not sure why android still not receiving the bytes where in PC it actually read bytes sent by FTDI chip (first try was similar settings as with the PC but still not getting the bytes so tried with other BAUD rate), from the MDB cable (communicating with vending machine)

Comment: @vimsliu 1. _have_ you actually read the PDF I just linked? 2. Are you actually doing anything to debug your code, because, as I say, if you get 5 from write - as documented in the PDF - it tried to write 5 bytes and if you are expecting it to write 2 bytes, something else is going very wrong. As for Java problems, I have no idea and I doubt whether many people on the _electrical engineering_ stack exchange will be able to help you debug Android code. You say (I think) it works on PC but not on Android, that pretty much means it's not hardware, so you need to be debugging the code.

Comment: Hi, because the PC version of the code is similar to the android version, I skipped the debugging. will try a different FTDI driver and see if it works (I think its a different in FTDI driver).

Comment: Hi, I was able to read the bytes sent from the FTDI driver, there was no code changes but the problem was its actually receiving wrong bytes and everything went to the else part which does nothing, no wander. now the problem is why the hardware that directly plugged to PC have correct bytes value received and why the hardware with FTDI plugged to android device gives wrong (different) bytes value.? I am not sure if there is a shift in bytes involve though